# Issue accessing data returned from an API with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a little past the noo-by stage with python but new to getting data from API's. I am having an issue extracting a piece of data from what is returned from an API.

I am using the "requests" module in python.

My code

```
import requests import json

url = "https://<my url.com/<locations>"
     resp = requests.get(url) r_dict = resp.json()
```

After this the value of the "r_dict" variable is

"[{'content': {'parameters': {'node_external_ip_list': '10.xx.yy.zz'}}}]".

The type is "<class 'list'>" and the length is 1.

I convert this to a dictionary with

```
my_dict = {}

for i in n_dict:
    my_dict.update(i)**
```

The value of my_dict is
"{'content': {'parameters': {'node_external_ip_list': '10.xx.yy.zz'}}}"

and is of type "<class 'dict'>" with a length of 1.

I am trying to extract the IP address from this dictionary

I have tried

```
my_dict2 = {}

    for i in my_dict:
        my_dict2.update(i)**
```

but I receive the error

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required*

If I use a print(i) instead of the update I see

"content': {'parameters': {'node_external_ip_list': '10.xx.yy.zz'}}"

I have also tried

```
result = json.dumps(my_dict, indent = 4)
```

and when I print "result" I see

> {
> "content": {
> "parameters": {
> "node_external_ip_list": "10.xx.yy.zz"
> }
> }  }

I have then tried

```
print(result\['content'\]\['parameters'\]\['emp_external_ip_list'\])
```

and

```
print(result[0]['content']['parameters']['emp_external_ip_list'])
```

and received

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers*

Is there anyway to extract the IP address either from the list r_dict or from the dictionary my_dict or from the json variable "result"?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the IP like this? `r_dict[0]['content']['parameters']['node_external_ip_list']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests

url = "https://<my url.com/<locations>"
resp = requests.get(url)
result = resp.json()
```

Note: I changed `r_dict` to `result` just to avoid the confusion since the result of the request is a list and not a dict.

Based on what you mentioned, the variable `result`, in the above code, will contain a list.

In Python, to access items in lists, you use the square brackets for slicing and the index to obtain the item available at that specific index. In this case, the list contains one and only item, so you access it with `result[0]`.

This item happens to be the following dictionary:

```json
{
  "content": {
    "parameters": {
      "node_external_ip_list": "10.xx.yy.zz"
    }
  }
}
```

To access elements in a dictionary, you can use the square brackets and the key to obtain its value. In this case, to obtain the value of `content`, we can use:

```py
content = result[0]["content"]
```

Again, the variable `content` will contain a dictionary and so will `result[0]["content"]["parameters"]`.

So, you can access the IP address as follows, without doing any conversion:

```py
ip_address = result[0]["content"]["parameters"]["node_external_ip_list"]
```

Comment: Hi @elmiomar, Thank you for your response, it is very much appreciated. It worked exactly as I required and you advised it would.